# Including iframe in tooltip in Marker?

Tags: python, leaflet, markers, folium, tooltip

Can we include an iframe in tooltip in Marker?

```
import folium

var=open("yolo.html", "r")

var2 = var.read()

map = folium.Map(location=[19.179180,72.972580],zoom_start=6, tiles="Mapbox Control Room")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="first layer")

iframe = folium.IFrame(html=var2, width=500, height=300)

popup = folium.Tooltip(iframe)

fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[19.279180,72.972680], tooltip=popup))

map.add_child(fg)

map.save("yolo1.html")
```